# Page order in list of acronyms with roman numbering

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries, indexing, acronyms

I have a document with three parts and different numbering: small roman numbers, arabic numbers and capital roman numbers. When printing the list of acronyms, the page order of an entry is always small roman number, capital roman number, arabic number, although the capital-roman-numbered pages are the last ones. How can I fix this?

`\glshyperlink`is not an option since I still want the page numbers to appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,toc,hyperfirst=true,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{a blue cherry}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{dry eggplant fruit}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{green humongous iceberg lettuce}
\newacronym{JKL}{JKL}{jelly kiwi lentils}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Today, I ate not only \ac{ABC}, but also \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Ac{ABC} is sweeter than a \ac{DEF}. And I ate a bit of \ac{GHI}.
The only thing I did not eat were \ac{JKL}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
~
\clearpage
\ac{JKL} are even worse than \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

[image: list of abbreviations]

---

EDIT: As was pointed out, the question boils down to "how do I teach `makeindex` to behave differently, or is there an alternative for `makeindex`?" with answers for both cases.

Comment: As far as I know, the page ordering is something that is done by `makeindex` which is underlying `glossaries`

Comment: I think, you need something like `page_precedence = "rnRAa"` in a `makeindex` style file

Comment: thanks for the hint, apparently, adding the option `xindy` to it solves the problem. I didn't know that`makeindex`was also responsible for the page numbers

Comment: I don't know about makeindex style files. But xindy apparently does the job for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `makeindex` is used and not `xindy`, there's a little bit more to do.

`makeindex` uses `.ist` (index style files) in which the precise setup for `glossaries` is written by `glossaries`  on-the-fly, unless an explicit different file is given.

Here is the file that is generated for the jobname `glossariespageorder.tex`:

```
% makeindex style file created by the glossaries package
% for document 'glossariespageorder' on 2016-3-29
actual '?'
encap '|'
level '!'
quote '"'
keyword "\\glossaryentry"
preamble "\\glossarysection[\\glossarytoctitle]{\\glossarytitle}\\glossarypreamble\n\\begin{theglossary}\\glossaryheader\n"
postamble "\%\n\\end{theglossary}\\glossarypostamble\n"
group_skip "\\glsgroupskip\n"
item_0 "\%\n"
item_1 "\%\n"
item_2 "\%\n"
item_01 "\%\n"
item_x1 "\\relax \\glsresetentrylist\n"
item_12 "\%\n"
item_x2 "\\relax \\glsresetentrylist\n"
delim_0 "\{\\glossaryentrynumbers\{\\relax "
delim_1 "\{\\glossaryentrynumbers\{\\relax "
delim_2 "\{\\glossaryentrynumbers\{\\relax "
delim_t "\}\}"
delim_n "\\delimN "
delim_r "\\delimR "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\glsgroupheading\{"
heading_suffix "\}\\relax \\glsresetentrylist "
symhead_positive "glssymbols"
numhead_positive "glsnumbers"
page_compositor "."
suffix_2p ""
suffix_3p ""
```

The crucial point for this issue about the page order is the `page_precedence` key which is by default "rRnaA", not "rnR" as requested by the O.P.

As far as I know there's no easy way to use `glossaries` to write user-defined settings into this `\jobname.ist` file.

Here's a hack that sets the `page_precedence` to "rnRAa", i.e. lower case Roman numbers, arabic numbers, upper case Roman numbers, uppercase letters and lower case letters`by writing into the`\glswrite` file.

**Improved version**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\usepackage[nomain,acronym,shortcuts,toc,hyperfirst=true,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}


\newcommand{\glspageprecedence}{rnRaA}

\newcommand{\glswritehookextra}{%
  \write\glswrite{page_precedence \string"\glspageprecedence\string"}
}

\xpatchcmd{\writeist}{%
  \fi
  \closeout\glswrite
  \let\writeist\relax
}{%
  \fi
  \glswritehookextra
  \closeout\glswrite
  \let\writeist\relax
}{}{\typeout{Error: patching \string\writeist failed}}


\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{a blue cherry}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{dry eggplant fruit}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{green humongous iceberg lettuce}
\newacronym{JKL}{JKL}{jelly kiwi lentils}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Today, I ate not only \ac{ABC}, but also \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Ac{ABC} is sweeter than a \ac{DEF}. And I ate a bit of \ac{GHI}.
The only thing I did not eat were \ac{JKL}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
~
\clearpage
\ac{JKL} are even worse than \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like that here I can play around with the precedence (should be possible with xindy, too). As noted in the comment to my answer, the best would be to automatically detect the order that was actually used in the document but that is not really necessary as this can be done by hand normally.

Comment: @riddleculous: well, this is difficult to track actually, in my point of view.

Comment: @riddleculous: I see another problem with your request: What if you have a very strange partition in, say, 8 parts, each one has a different page numbering style, e.g. arabic, roman, Alpha, Roman, Greek, lower case greek, alpha, Klingon letters, or mixing styles, occuring again ;-) How should this be tracked?

Comment: please don't understand it as a request, it would be nice but I have actually no particular use for that myself. It all depends how the text is scanned for the acronyms. If you just go from top to bottom and note down the appearances, then you should get something like "i, ii, 5, 39, III, XIV, H, f" for a certain acronym and nobody should have to care about which pagenumber style has been used when

Answer (score 3):

Changing from the default `makeindex`to `xindy` solves the problem: add the package option `xindy`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym,shortcuts,toc,hyperfirst=true,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{a blue cherry}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{dry eggplant fruit}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{green humongous iceberg lettuce}
\newacronym{JKL}{JKL}{jelly kiwi lentils}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Today, I ate not only \ac{ABC}, but also \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Ac{ABC} is sweeter than a \ac{DEF}. And I ate a bit of \ac{GHI}.
The only thing I did not eat were \ac{JKL}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
~
\clearpage
\ac{JKL} are even worse than \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it will still use roman, arabic, Roman as an order, even if first the page numbering is changed to arabic first, then Roman and finally roman. I don't need this but if anyone knows how to recognize the page numbering order and adjusting xindy automatically, it might be interesting for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As from `glossaries` v4.24 (2016-05-27), you can use

```
\GlsSetWriteIstHook{\write\glswrite{page_precedence "rnR"}}
```

before `\makeglossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,toc,hyperfirst=true,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\GlsSetWriteIstHook{\write\glswrite{page_precedence "rnR"}}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{a blue cherry}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{dry eggplant fruit}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{green humongous iceberg lettuce}
\newacronym{JKL}{JKL}{jelly kiwi lentils}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Today, I ate not only \ac{ABC}, but also \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Ac{ABC} is sweeter than a \ac{DEF}. And I ate a bit of \ac{GHI}.
The only thing I did not eat were \ac{JKL}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
~
\clearpage
\ac{JKL} are even worse than \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

However, this requires you to know the page ordering in your document. If you want to work it out on the fly, it's possible to adjust the behaviour of `\pagenumbering` and build a list of the ordering. Since the ist file is generated by `\makeglossaries`, which is a preamble-only command, the information either has to be saved in an external file and read in on the next run or the creation of the ist file needs to be deferred until the end of the document.

Here's an example of the first approach, which creates a temporary file with the extension `.tmp`. (The `.aux` file can't be used in this case, as it's not read until the start of the document.)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,toc,hyperfirst=true,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\def\pageordering{rnaRA}% makeindex's default

\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tmp}
{%
  \GlsSetWriteIstHook{\write\glswrite{page_precedence "\pageordering"}}
}
{%
}

\def\thispageordering{}%

\newwrite\tmpfile
\openout\tmpfile=\jobname.tmp

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\tmpfile{\string\def\string\pageordering{\thispageordering}}
  \closeout\tmpfile
}

\let\orgpagenumbering\pagenumbering
\renewcommand{\pagenumbering}[1]{%
  \orgpagenumbering{#1}%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{arabic}%
  {%
    \appto\thispageordering{n}%
  }%
  {%
     \addpageordering#1\endaddpageordering
  }%
}

\def\addpageordering#1#2\endaddpageordering{%
  \appto\thispageordering{#1}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{a blue cherry}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{dry eggplant fruit}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{green humongous iceberg lettuce}
\newacronym{JKL}{JKL}{jelly kiwi lentils}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Today, I ate not only \ac{ABC}, but also \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Ac{ABC} is sweeter than a \ac{DEF}. And I ate a bit of \ac{GHI}.
The only thing I did not eat were \ac{JKL}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
~
\clearpage
\ac{JKL} are even worse than \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

This requires two LaTeX runs before `makeindex` can be run.

Now for the second approach. To do this, first prevent `\makeglossaries` from writing the ist file using `\noist`. Since `\writeist` and `\GlsSetWriteIstHook` are preamble only commands, their original definitions need to be saved before they're disabled.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,toc,hyperfirst=true,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\newcommand\pageordering{}

\let\orgwriteist\writeist
\let\orgGlsSetWriteIstHook\GlsSetWriteIstHook
\noist

\AtEndDocument{%
  \orgGlsSetWriteIstHook{\write\glswrite{page_precedence "\pageordering"}}
  \orgwriteist
}

\let\orgpagenumbering\pagenumbering
\renewcommand{\pagenumbering}[1]{%
  \orgpagenumbering{#1}%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{arabic}%
  {%
     \appto\pageordering{n}%
  }%
  {%
     \addpageordering#1\endaddpageordering
  }%
}

\def\addpageordering#1#2\endaddpageordering{%
  \appto\pageordering{#1}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{a blue cherry}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{dry eggplant fruit}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{green humongous iceberg lettuce}
\newacronym{JKL}{JKL}{jelly kiwi lentils}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Today, I ate not only \ac{ABC}, but also \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Ac{ABC} is sweeter than a \ac{DEF}. And I ate a bit of \ac{GHI}.
The only thing I did not eat were \ac{JKL}.
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
~
\clearpage
\ac{JKL} are even worse than \acp{DEF}.
\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]
\end{document}
```

[image: image of result]