# sorting using makeindex.exe with page_precedence option in style file

Tags: indexing, sorting, makeindex

Suppose I would like to sort an index file called "xchp.idx" that includes the following information:

```
    \indexentry{{Chp  1 } cherry}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  1 } apple}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  1 } banana}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  2 } banana}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  2 } cherry}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  2 } apple}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  10 } banana}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  10 } cherry}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  10 } apple}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  12 } apple}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  12 } cherry}{1}
    \indexentry{{Chp  12 } banana}{1}
```

If I attempt such a sort operation using

```
    makeindex xchp.idx
```

then I get

```
    \item {Chp  1 } apple, 1  
    \item {Chp  1 } banana, 1 
    \item {Chp  1 } cherry, 1 
    \item {Chp  10 } apple, 1 
    \item {Chp  10 } banana, 1
    \item {Chp  10 } cherry, 1
    \item {Chp  12 } apple, 1 
    \item {Chp  12 } banana, 1
    \item {Chp  12 } cherry, 1
    \item {Chp  2 } apple, 1  
    \item {Chp  2 } banana, 1 
    \item {Chp  2 } cherry, 1
```

This is sorting everything lexicographically, whereas I would like the second token in each string to be sorted numerically like this:

```
    \item {Chp  1 } apple, 1  
    \item {Chp  1 } banana, 1 
    \item {Chp  1 } cherry, 1 
    \item {Chp  2 } apple, 1  
    \item {Chp  2 } banana, 1 
    \item {Chp  2 } cherry, 1 
    \item {Chp  10 } apple, 1 
    \item {Chp  10 } banana, 1
    \item {Chp  10 } cherry, 1
    \item {Chp  12 } apple, 1 
    \item {Chp  12 } banana, 1
    \item {Chp  12 } cherry, 1
```

To that end, I might try to use the "page_precedence" option in a style file called "xchp.ist" containing this:

```
    page_precedence "anaan"
```

where a=alphabetic lower and n=numeric.

Here I might be tempted to complain, that while this option is mentioned 
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339403/sorting-of-roman-and-arabic-page-numbers-in-index/339410#339410) and 
[there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298519/using-imakeidx-with-custom-page-numbering/352559#352559) on 
[stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301442/page-order-in-list-of-acronyms-with-roman-numbering/301453#301453),
there seems to be no clear documentation to its use...not even in Table 11.1 of "The LaTeX Companion" second edition.
But then I would stop myself from complaining, and profusely apologize, because I am getting makeindex for free ... 
and so who am I to complain?

Now if I try

```
    makeindex -s xchp.ist xchp.idx
```

I get

```
    \item {Chp  1 } apple, 1  
    \item {Chp  1 } banana, 1 
    \item {Chp  1 } cherry, 1     
    \item {Chp  10 } apple, 1 
    \item {Chp  10 } banana, 1
    \item {Chp  10 } cherry, 1
    \item {Chp  12 } apple, 1 
    \item {Chp  12 } banana, 1
    \item {Chp  12 } cherry, 1
    \item {Chp  2 } apple, 1  
    \item {Chp  2 } banana, 1 
    \item {Chp  2 } cherry, 1
```

Which is still not what I want. Can anyone help me out? 
I suspect that xindy may have a solution. But that may be another post. For now, is there a way to perform
the desired operation with makeindex?

Comment: If the sort value is purely numerical, `makeindex` will perform a numerical sort, so you'd need the entries to be in the form `\indexentry{1@{Chp  1 } cherry}{1}`.

Comment: Assume the xchp.idx file is non-editable (carved in stone or burned into ROM, or a protected world heritage site). Is there a solution under this constraint?

Comment: Can't think of how to do it in `makeindex` without changing the index file. Are you willing to use a pipe (`sed` etc)? The `page_precedence` setting relates to the page number ordering (in the second argument of `\indexentry`). So if you have `\indexentry{foo}{IX}`, `\indexentry{foo}{10}` and `\indexentry{foo}{xii}` then `page_precedence "rnR"` will put the lower-case roman numerals at the start of the page list, followed by the arabic numerals, followed by upper case roman numerals. So you end up with `foo, xii, 10, IX`.

Comment: What about using `xindy`? Interestingly, it seems to work out of the box. Try `texindy xchap.idx`

Comment: Oh, I just read your last sentence! Sorry! Never mind, perhaps my answer will give you enough information to use `xindy`.

Comment: Thank you @NicolaTalbot for your very useful reply. Often having a negative solution of "No Solution" is just as useful as a positive solution---it saves me much wasted time digging around trying to find a method that does not exist. It is a little curious though---I read that makeindex.exe was written in C, and C has the function strtok(...), which allows one to parse "tokens" separated by delimiters, which is basically what I want.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPurton for your xindy recommendation. I did try texindy xchap.idx, but got an error with "input file xchap.idx does not exist at" [a texlive distribution path]. That is, it seems to be looking for my xchap.idx file in the same directory as texindy.pl. I suspect maybe that this problem may be resolved if I let xelatex call texindy implicitly, but I prefer to call it explicitly myself from within a makefile (perhaps due to some distorted world view). I will continue to tinker around with it. If I can't get it working, I will likely post again in a separate thread.

Comment: I more often have trouble with `texindy` running from within `latex` and have to run it manually. So it's meant to work fine. Asking a separate question is probably your best option.

Comment: @DavidPurton `makeindex` is on the restricted list (that is, it's a trusted application) so it can be run using TeX's shell escape in restricted mode. `xindy` isn't on the restricted list (there's a comment about it in `texmf.cnf`) so it can't be run from the shell escape in restricted mode. It needs the unrestricted `-shell-escape` which is less secure.

Comment: Whoa. So surprising. Today I tried `texindy xchp.idx` again, and this time it worked giving me an `xchp.ind` file (not the error message I got before). And, as @DavidPurton said, it sorted correctly ("correctly" here meaning the way I egocentrically wanted it). I don't know what happened before. But the good news is, based on past experience, once an intermittent problem appears once, it will likely appear again. Something to look forward to. Many thanks to Nicola and David again, and to stackexchange, even though apparently it will not support me using @ tags in the same comment twice.

Comment: I also tested using `texindy xchp.idx` on a much larger xelatex project with `\indexentry` statements involving font size switching, typeface switching, Asian glyphs, a teckit mapping (for PinYin tone diacritic marks), and hyper-link support, like this ...

        \indexentry{{\relax \fontsize  {8}{9.5}\selectfont  1} brain(n) {\fntNotoSansCJK 頭腦}({t/'ou n/>ao})|hyperpage}{3}

Everything appears to work "correctly" right out of the box.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it correctly using `xindy`.

Compile it using `pdflatex -shell-escape`. If it doesn't run `xindy`, you might have to do that manually (`texindy`), then run `pdflatex` again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage,xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}
\begin{document}
Filler text.
\index{{Chp  1 } cherry}
\index{{Chp  1 } apple}
\index{{Chp  1 } banana}
\index{{Chp  2 } banana}
\index{{Chp  2 } cherry}
\index{{Chp  2 } apple}
\index{{Chp  10 } banana}
\index{{Chp  10 } cherry}
\index{{Chp  10 } apple}
\index{{Chp  12 } apple}
\index{{Chp  12 } cherry}
\index{{Chp  12 } banana}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]